# declaring some class parameters outside a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, methods

I would like to understand why in the `1_settings.rb` rails app initializing app, some method of the `Settings` paramaters are declared outside the class `Settings`. Why does it mean exactly ? Can we take those as `Settings` methods ? (if so, why not include them in the class )

Btw, where is the `namespace` keyword defined (does it refer to a ruby keyword or all elsewhere defined `namespace` class )?

```
class Settings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/applab.yml"
  namespace Rails.env

  class << self
    def applab_on_non_standard_port?
      ![443, 80].include?(applab.port.to_i)
    end
...    
  end
end

...
# Default settings
Settings['ldap'] ||= Settingslogic.new({})
Settings.ldap['enabled'] = false if Settings.ldap['enabled'].nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings['ldap'] ||= Settingslogic.new({})
```

is equivalent to:

```
Settings.[]('ldap') || Settings.[]=('ldap', Settingslogic.new({}))
```

So these are simply methods `[]` and `[]=` called on `Settings` class (which is also an object) with proper parameters.

Comment: sorry, I am really not familiar to ruby, what are those `[]` and `[]=` methods

Comment: @Newben I don't understand your question. Could you be more precise?

Comment: in fact I guess `.[]=` is a shortcut, but of what ? Btw, why declaring methods of a class outside a class but on the same file

Comment: No, the other way. `Settings[]` is shortcut for `Settings.[]()`

Comment: @Newben just as @MichaelSzyndler said - `Settings[]` is syntax sugar for `Settings.[]()`. This construction is not declaring a method, but calling (already defined) method. Why are they called that way? Probably because it is clearer than calling them inside of a class.